# Custom bindhtmlunsafe directive display html

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('directives.bindhtmlunsafe', [])
.directive('bindHtmlUnsafe', function( $parse, $compile ) {
     return function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.addClass('ng-binding').data('$binding', attr.ngBindHtmlUnsafe);
        scope.$watch(attr.ngBindHtmlUnsafe, function ngBindHtmlUnsafeWatchAction(value) {
            element.html(value || '');
        });
    }
});
```

Made a custom directive that allows the user to render arbitrary HTML into the DIV, It does show me anything but when window.print invoke don't know why any idea please guuide

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is creating problem please check your view code there may be some condition thing or hidden style persist this issue.

Thanks